# SSIS - Pass value from For Loop Item Enumerator to Executesqltask

Tags: ssis

How to pass variable from For Loop Item Enumerator to Executesqltask

Answer (score 1):

assuming you know how to use the for loop, you should go to the "variable mapping" tab and map the result of the loop to packages variables. So if you are looping on a folder to get all the files in it, you could map the index 0 (right column) to a variable called @fileName (left column) so on each iteration the loop will read a file name and store on the @fileName variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my problem is i am using for each Item Enumerator loop and i have declared a variable in variable mapping.In for each loop i am using execute sql task in which i am using connection type as ado.net, using the for each loop variable in it as parameter, here while executing i am getting error. So how use the loop variable in execute sql task.